# Get all occurrences of substring matching pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that's on this form:

```
"Some text [asd](fgh) Lorem Ipsum [qwert](y)"
```

You might recognize this as markdown syntax.

I want to replace all occurences of the pattern with links like this:

```
<a href="fgh">asd</a>
```

What would be the best way to do this? I can do the actual replacing without problem, but I'm not sure about how to identify the substrings. I suspect regex is the way to go?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: If you think that regex is the only way to go then I think that you should provide actual examples. Regular expressions are highly scope-specific.

Comment: Damn, I'd messed up the formatting and I've been AFK for a few hours so I din't catch it until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think regex is OK here:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"\[     # Match [
    (        # Match and capture in group 1:
     [^][]*  #  Any number of characters except brackets
    )        # End of capturing group 1
    \]       # Match ]
    \(       # Match (
    (        # Match and capture in group 2:
     [^()]*  #  Any number of characters except parentheses
    )        # End of capturing group 2
    \)       # Match )", 
    "<a href=\"$2\">$1</a>", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```